# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'

Tags: python, loops, sequence, text-segmentation

I just began studying Python and I am currently trying to count the frequency of character sequences in a segmentation (segment into words). I have a problem with my `count_seq` function. In this function I want in the first loop to go fetch each segment of the segmentation (in_object) and then in the second loop I am counting the sequences.
From what I tried to change and understand I think the problem definitely lies in the `for idx in range` loop.
The problem is this, when I try to run the script I have this TypeError : " TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'int'" which I do not understand.

```
def main():
    seq_length = 3
    freq_dict = count_seq(in_object, seq_length)
    print_freq(freq_dict)


def count_seq(segmentation, seq_length):
    freq_dict = dict()


    for idx in range(len(segmentation)):
        freq_dict[idx] = dict()
        segments = segmentation[idx].get_content()

    for pos in range(len(segments)):
        char = segments[pos:pos+seq_length]
        if len(char) < seq_length:
            continue
        freq_dict[char] = freq_dict.get(char, 0)+1
    return freq_dict


def print_freq(freq_dict):
    """Recuperer le contenu de la fonction de l'exercice 2..."""
    for key in sorted(freq_dict, key=freq_dict.get, reverse=True):
        print("%s:%s" %(key, freq_dict[key]))




if __name__ == "builtins":
    if in_objects:
        main()
```

Comment: Can you post a [mre]?

Answer (score 2):

This error is happening when you call `sorted`.  The way items are sorted is by comparing them against each other.  Some of the values of your `freq_dict` are `dict`s, and some of them are `int`s, which cannot be compared against each other (which is less:  7 or a dictionary?  It doesn't make sense).

If you want to sort in this way, you need to make sure all values in `freq_dict` are comparable types.

In this block you set a bunch of keys to an empty dict:

```
for idx in range(len(segmentation)):
    freq_dict[idx] = dict()
```

Then in your next loop, you set another set of keys to `int`s.

What is your goal for `freq_dict` to be at the end?

Comment: At the end, `freq_dict` should be printed and display each sequence and its corresponding frequency.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to fill it up with `dict`s to start, or what you were hoping to accomplish with the first loop.  Since we don't know what `segmentation` is, it's hard to give you suggestions for a fix.